# Bootstrap menu is not pushing down the body text

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site which uses Bootstrap for the front end side.

I have noticed when I click the hamburger menu at mobile level, the main body content doesn't push down so the menu overlaps :-(

Here is my **Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/8kvgoxw3/

How do I resolve this?

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%
}
h1, .navbar-collapse ul li a, p, .nav-tabs > li > h2 > a, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-weight: 300!important
}

h3 {
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding-bottom:10px
}

h3 a, h3 a:hover {
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}

h4 {
  margin-bottom:0;
}

h5 {
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.item div div {    
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
.cbp-af-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.cbp-af-header img{
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.cbp-af-inner {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.cbp-af-header{
  -webkit-animation-name:fadeInDown;
  -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
  -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -moz-animation-name:anim_titles;
  -moz-animation-direction:normal;
  -moz-animation-play-state:running;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
  -webkit-animation-duration:.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration:.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
}

/*body.body-class .container.body-text {
margin-top: 140px;
}*/

.cbp-af-header .cbp-af-inner img {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink .cbp-af-inner img {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink {
  height: 160px;
}

.cbp-af-header {
  height: 355px;
}

.cbp-af-header.cbp-af-header-shrink img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 42%;
  height:unset;
}

button {
  background:black!important;
  z-index:99999999;
  position:relative;
}

.container.body-text {
  margin-top: 140px; 
}

.nav {
  background:blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="center-block text-center" style="text-align:center">
            <div class="cbp-af-header">
              <div class="cbp-af-inner">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="logo">
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                                                                                                  <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="/test/">Test</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="/test/">Test</a></li>
                    <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="/test/">Test</a></li>
                    <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="/test/">Test</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container body-text">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1 style="line-height:28px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus dolor et velit sodales, a pretium metus finibus. Vivamus lacinia a ligula vitae volutpat. Curabitur nulla lectus, aliquam ac massa at, lacinia mattis odio. Vivamus vitae orci urna. In iaculis sem a eleifend sollicitudin. Curabitur varius, felis vel efficitur condimentum, sapien est condimentum nibh, convallis faucibus sem tortor a purus. Aenean consequat nec diam quis aliquam. Aenean laoreet felis ac tincidunt iaculis. Quisque eu ipsum eget tortor sodales vehicula. Mauris sem lacus, tincidunt id sem id, posuere mollis velit. Nam enim magna, vulputate id eleifend eu, consectetur vel leo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Header must be `fixed` position, Hence it is not pushing the content to down. From your CSS,

```
.cbp-af-header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
          transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }
    .cbp-af-header img{
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }
```

Remove the `fixed` position might work for you.

Comment: Is it possible to rectify this issue without removing this? It's just I need this to do a transition with my header and removing it breaks this.

Comment: You need to play with the CSS for this. Try like this,
 While the Menu is open, there sholud be toggling of the class in your HTML element. Using that that class hierarchy make the position to `position: static`. I mean when the menu is open make that to station, if it is close make it to Fixed. But i am not sure it will work properly with this solution. Needs to look on the CSS and and HTML on live.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the margin-top and push that certain content down to the right position. If you test it on mobile it wont mess up the mobile compatibility. If it still des not go down add the !important.

Comment: Can you possibly show me how to do this using my demo?

Comment: Yea this is using regular bootstrap 3.5 +

Comment: give me a sec putting it on my domain

Comment: i think you are not setting up the navbar correctly

Comment: do you want the image in the navbar

Comment: I think it would be best to place this above the navigation bar.

Comment: I'm using this code here for the header area: https://codepen.io/rahue88/pen/exyIo

Comment: ok i basically made it look like the example on the codepen and you can just edit it

Comment: Awesome - do you have a link? :-)

Comment: Then you can just change the text to an image

Comment: and change the text and a few other stuff

Comment: Aaah ok. So this removes the hamburger menu?

Comment: hamburger menu?